# R ifelse pumping out NAs

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to count "chunks" of similar consecutive numbers in a vector. But my code is spitting back "NA"s when I expect it to be putting in either a "1" or a "0"

```
x <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
y <- c(0)

turing <- function(x){
  y <- c(0)
  for (i in length(x)){
    ifelse(isTRUE(x[i] == x[i+1]), y[i]<-0, y[i]<-1)
  }
  y
}
turing(x)
```

This spits out
`[1]  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1`

EDIT: The following seems to work fine:

```
turing <- function(x){
  y <-  numeric(length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)){
    ifelse(isTRUE(x[i] == x[i+1]), y[i] <-0 , y[i] <- 1)
  }
  y
}
```

As it spits out 
`0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1`
Thanks!

Comment: in your function you have  preassigned 'y' to a single value.

Comment: Even if I don't, the same thing happens

Comment: the `i+1` and `length(x)` are issues

Comment: How so? How would I tell the if/then statement to check the i value against the one next to it?

Comment: `for (i in length(x))` `length` of 'x' is just a single value

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: right, for i in however long x is, so it will run the for loop 9 times

Comment: Can you just  print `for(i in length(x)) print(i)`.  it will print only 9.

Comment: Can you update with the expected output

Comment: I'd expect something along the lines of (0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)

Comment: You can check my modifieed versioin of your code

Comment: Hello @IG2020, if you compare consecutive n numbers, you'll have n-1 values

Answer (score 3):

If we need a count sequence, can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rleid(x)
```

---

or with `rle` from `base R`

```
with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

---

With OP's code, can pre-assign 'y' as a vector with `length` equal to that of length of x, then loop over the sequence of 'x' (instead of 'length' as length is just a single number), then do `if/else` (`ifelse` is vectorized option and as we are doing this in a loop `if/else` is only needed)

```
turing <- function(x){
    y <-  numeric(length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)){
    if(i < length(x)) {
      if(x[i] == x[i+1]) {
        y[i]<-0
        } else y[i]<-1
    }}
    y[length(y)] <- 1

    y
  }

turing(x)
#[1] 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to write a function specifically for this task. It's just stumping me.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this works for you:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
y <- c(0)

turing <- function(x){
  j<- 1
  for (i in x){
    y[j] <- ifelse((x[j] == x[j+1]), 0, 1)
    j <- j+1
  }
  y
}
turing(x)
```

Thanks for pointing out the previous mistake @akrun

Comment: Why? It runs on R, perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @akrun, please don't get me wrong, I respect the fact that you helped me before, so my question is why is it wrong. Please, consider that I am learning too, and a mistake can take me to a better me in R

Comment: What i meant is that you are doing the assignment `y[i] <- 0` inside `ifelse.  instead it can be `y[j] <- ifelse((x[j] == x[j+1]), 0, 1)`  In this case it works, but it is a potential for bug

Answer (score 3):

I will add one more answer since all previous answers have missed that cool thing with the function `ifelse` is that i works on the whole vector so you dont need any for loop and index

```
turing <- function(x){
  ifelse(x[1:length(x)-1] == x[2:length(x)], 0,1)
}
turing(x)
```

you can also use the function `lead` from the dplyr package to have it a bit more clean

```
ifelse(x == dplyr::lead(x), 0,1)
```

Hope this helps!!